# Spring 4.1.1 RELEASE and @ResponseBody return HTTP 406

Tags: json, spring-mvc, http-status-code-406

I am using @ResponseBody to return Json object in Spring MVC. It works as expected on release 4.0.7 and 3.2.11, but it returns HTTP status 406 when I try to use the latest Spring release 4.1.1(as of 10/16) with no any other configuration changes. Is this considered a bug or the 4.1.1 requires different configuration?

the latest jackson jar is already in the classpath

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

The example on the Spring [document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-responsebody) works fine

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public String helloWorld() {
  return "Hello World";
}
```

when the return type is String. The problem happens when the return type is a POJO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maven pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

and spring mvc config file (eg:spring-mvc.xml)

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: After I added `jackson-databind`(and the only extra jar I added, which is not required prior to 4.1.1 RELEASE), it works now. To wrap up, in order for @ResponseBody to work on Spring 4.1.1, I have `jackson-mapper-asl` and `jackson-databind` jars and `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in the config file. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Why would you include two versions of Jackson?

Comment: @DinoTw you can read this post:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework#enforced-minimum-dependency-versions

Comment: @Vito, thanks for the update. Found that the minimum jars required for `@ResponseBody` to work are spring-webmvc and jackson-databind.

Comment: @Vito You lost a dependence: jackson-annotaions. I tested it in spring 4.2.4, which required jackson-annotaions.

Comment: Thanks @Vito, this is what I was actually looking for. Thanks a lot buddy

Answer (score 8):

Got it working after removing Jackson 1.* replacing with the 2.4.4 (JAXRS), which will import all the other dependencies, jackson-core, jackson-databind and jackson-annotations.

**Removed**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

**Added**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/jquery-ui-autocomplete-not-working-in-spring-4-1/

and in the servlet xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven  content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />

<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
     <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
     <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
     <property name="mediaTypes" >
          <value>
               json=application/json
               xml=application/xml
          </value>
     </property>
</bean>
```

if the jackson annotate is imported in the class files, it should also be replaced

**Removed**

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties

**Added**

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties

Comment: Thank you for the answer, will verify it later.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with similar issue migrating from 3.2 to spring 4.2.
Was getting

### org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type:

posting it here so people can find it by exception name :) It took me half a day to find this article. Thanks @Vito and @Aias

Combination of both previous answers work as well, if you do not want register custom `contentNegotiationManager` you can do following:

remove all jackson dependencies from

### pom.xml

and use latest one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

### servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```