# Spring Error: only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Im using spring to build a Restful API and when I access the method below:

```
// get the entity in DB by using id number
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    User getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") String email) {
        User user=null;
        System.out.println(email);
        try {
            user = dataServices.getEntityById(email);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(user.getNickname());
        return user;
    }
```

with this URL: http://localhost:8080/RestCrud/user/richard_johnson@sina.com

it gets 406 error:

[image]

I make sure I have added the

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in my spring-config.xml.
[image]

Im also sure I added those jackson dependencies in pom.xml

[image]

********************edit*************************************

[image]

********************edit again*******************************

as you can see I did not restrict headers in the @RequestMapping annotation, so I dont think its an issue related to the header restriction.

Also, my url patterns are like:

[image]
[image]

http://localhost:8080/RestCrud/user/id

Ive tested the "list" 
http://localhost:8080/RestCrud/user/list

and it works, but the "id" path does not

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hmm, where has the request origin from? And what is the request accept header? The cause might be there...

Comment: my question is how to solve this 406 ;)

Comment: Hi Serge ive edited my post according to you question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have commented out a few jackson dependencies 
The error occured because your employee object couldnt be converted to a format accceptable by the browser. You definitley would have wanted to respond with json.

Spring 4 required the following jackson libs

- jackson-core
- jackson-core-sal
- jackson-mapper-asl
- jackson-databind

Updated:

Looking at your URL pattern , the ***.com** extension is pushing spring to perform a content negotiation rather than verifying the accept headers.

You can force spring not to do content negotiation based on path extension using

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />

<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Jozzy ive edited the post, even thought I added those dependencies, still not work

Answer (score 0):

Look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615416/406-spring-mvc-json-not-acceptable-according-to-the-request-accept-headers), in short make sure you are including the `jackson-core` and `jackson-databind` dependencies if you are using Spring 4

Comment: Hi dim ive edited the post, even thought I added those dependencies, still not work