# request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers in postman

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

in my service application i want to get list by passing particular emailID.I have used below path in postman http://localhost:8081/Services/sample/kala@gmail.com but i am getting exception saying

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers

below are my code

spring.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.service.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=sample" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="paa" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.service.model.Details</value>
                 <value>com.service.model.MasterSpeed</value>
                  <value>com.service.model.CandidateDetails</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>

                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="dataDao" class="com.service.dao.DataDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="dataServices" class="com.service.services.DataServicesImpl"></bean>
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sampleapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <context.path>sampleapp</context.path>
    </properties>




    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <update>true</update>
                    <url>http://localhost:8081/manager/text</url>
                    <server>Tomcat</server>
                    <path>/sampleapp</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <finalName>sampleapp-File</finalName>

    </build>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Controller.java

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/addEntity")
   public class RestController {
             /* Getting List of objects in Json format in Spring Restful Services */  
             @RequestMapping(value = "/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
             public @ResponseBody  List getCandidateDetailsbyId(@PathVariable("email") String email) {  


              List candDetails = null;  
              try {  
                  candDetails = dataServices.getDetailbyId(email);  

              } catch (Exception e) {  
               e.printStackTrace();  
              }  

              return candDetails;  
             }  }
```

Please guide me in this issue.any help and suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31983639) to a similar question. It also has a url ending in an email address. The .com at the end caused problems with content negotiation.

Answer (score 0):

Configure this jackson dependency in your *POM*:

```
<properties>
 ...
 <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
 ...
</properties>
```

Then

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: after putting above code in pom.xml i am not able to access the url it gives the same error.