# spring mvc 4 result to jquery jtable

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, jquery-jtable

In Spring MVC 4 controller i am getting in capital letter

```
{ "Result":"OK", 
"Records":[ ....... ]}
```

which is requred for Jquery Jtable 
but when it reaches js it is converting to

```
 { "result":"OK",
 "records":[ ....... ]}
```

and a **blank alert message popup.** 
I am using below json dependency with spring mvc 4.0.1.RELEASE , Hibernate 4.2.1-Final

`org.codehaus.jackson
            jackson-mapper-asl
            1.9.13
         
        
            com.fasterxml.jackson.core
            jackson-core
            2.4.1
        
        
            com.fasterxml.jackson.core
            jackson-databind
            2.4.1.1`

Please let me know if any one have any solution and why it is converting into lowercase automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution for this issue.
just remove this from pom.xml

**Remove**

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Use** below dependencies in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and change the jackson property(import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty) to fasterxml property(
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty) in your classes. I hope this may be useful sor some one. below post will also help

[Spring 4.1.1 RELEASE and @ResponseBody return HTTP 406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416248/spring-4-1-1-release-and-responsebody-return-http-406)